# How do I delete "AUTO_INCREMENT=" from my input sql documents?

Tags: perl, file-io, substitution

I am new to Perl so my syntax might be off.  I have been reading other questions asked but still have not gotten it to work.

The problem is something to do with the line:

```
@fileinput =~s/AUTO_INCREMENT=//d;
```

If you could give me some pointers to get it to work that would be great.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
@file_names = ("eV12_No_Data.sql", "V12_No_Data.sql");

foreach(@file_names)
{
    openFile(@file_names);
}

sub openFile(@names)
{
    open(FILE, "+<@names");
    my @fileinput = <FILE>;
    foreach (@fileinput){
        @fileinput =~s/AUTO_INCREMENT=//d;
    }
    print FILE @fileinput;
    close(FILE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lot of errors here. You are using your loops incorrectly. You are calling `openFile` for the entire array, once per element in the array. The correct version is probably:

```
foreach (@file_names) {
    openFile($_);
}
```

Your sub is built incorrectly. In perl, you do not put arguments inside parens behind the sub name. That space is for prototypes (which you do not want to mess with). Your arguments are stored in the implicit variable `@_`.

```
sub openFile {
    my @names = @_;  # args are stored in @_
```

But this is also wrong, if you intend to open just one file.

```
my $file = shift;  # shift an argument from @_
```

Your open statement is incorrect. When you put an array in double quotes, it is interpolated with spaces placed between arguments. E.g.

```
@array = ("file.txt", "file2.txt");
print "@array"; # prints "file.txt file2.txt"
```

You do not check the return value of the open statement, which means it can fail silently (which it probably does in this case). Use:

```
open my $fh, "<", $file or die $!; # three arg open with lexical file handle
```

You probably do not want to mess around with trixy read/write dual opens. What you are doing here is reading to the end of the file, then appending data to the end. Write the data to a temp file, then swap it back. Or make use of the inplace-edit, but I would not recommend that for you, since you do not seem too experienced. You can also `seek` to the beginning of the file, but again, I would not do that, as it is just as simple to reopen the file.

This statement is also wrong.

```
@fileinput =~s/AUTO_INCREMENT=//d;
```

It will put your array in scalar context, which will translate to you trying to perform a substitution on a number. Also, as far as I know, there is no `/d` modifier.

Just remove the array, and use

```
s/AUTO_INCREMENT=//;
```

...instead. This will be equivalent to `$_ =~ s/...`. `$_` is the default variable perl uses when no explicit variable is given.

But why make things hard on yourself? Just use a one-liner:

```
perl -i.bak -pwe 's/AUTO_INCREMENT=//g' eV12_No_Data.sql V12_No_Data.sql
```

This will save a backup copy of the files with a ".bak" extension, and will loop through the files with the `-p` switch, performing the substitution multiple times per line (because of `/g` modifier, remove it to just remove first occurrence).

When writing perl code, it is always very vital to remember to use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

As it will help you catch errors, and save you a lot of time debugging typos and other such annoyances.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I did try this and I must have some other error because it is still not being replaced.

Comment: @andrewwhitley Yes, there were not many correct lines in your script. It was just the first thing that caught my eye, and I responded before I read through the rest of the code... =)

Comment: Your edited post covers it pretty all. SO does not update the page when writing a post when somebody edits ... I could have saved my time and just make a +1 ;)

Comment: @dgw I did not realize exactly how much commenting the code needed when I started to edit.. =) It did take quite a while.

Comment: Well thank you very much for all your comments! It was very helpful because if you couldn't tell it was my first time with Perl...

Comment: @andrewwhitley I had a feeling. Be sure to take your time studying the documentation. http://perldoc.perl.org/ is a nice online resource.

Comment: Oh and the one-liner was missing a ;

Comment: @andrewwhitley My one-liner? Surely not. `;` is only required to separate statements. In this case, there are no other statements.

Comment: @TLP Hmm that's weird, it would not work until I added it.  I also changed the single quote to double quotes so maybe that was it.

Comment: @andrew If you're in windows you need to use double quotes at the command prompt. It does not change this perl code, though.

Answer (score 0):

With lexical filehandle, map and e voila ... works.

```
use strict ;
use warnings ;

my @file_names = ("eV12_No_Data.sql", "V12_No_Data.sql");

foreach my $file ( @file_names ) {
    open my $filehandle , '+<' , $file or die "Cannot read/write $file" ;
    my @content = map { s/AUTO_INCREMENT=// ; $_ } <$filehandle> ;
    seek $filehandle, 0, 0 ;
    print $filehandle @content ;
    close $filehandle ;
}
```

Edit: rewinding filehandle

Comment: `map s/AUTO_INCREMENT=//r, <$fh>` is nice if you have perl v5.14. Though if you're using this method, don't forget to rewind the file before printing to it.

Comment: @TLP I read about the `/r` modifier ... sounds pretty nice. Rewinding ... yeah, you are right.

Comment: Also, it is not required to explicitly close the file handle in this case. A lexical file handle will autoclose when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @TLP Yes ... its just a habbit to clean up.